# Can't get magento installed on my mac

Tags: php, macos, magento

I'm trying to install Magento CE 1.7.0.2 on Mountain Lion 10.8

I'm able to do it using MAMP, but the problem is I need to move my database files to a different location and MAMP does not allow this.

I switch to a clean install of Mountain Lion, and used homebrew to install mcrypt.

I got everything pretty much enabled, but when I run the domain/magento-check.php file to make sure I meet the requirements, I get a garbled php output.

Here is what I'm seeing. Anyone know what might be the cause of this?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the PHP module isn't even activated...

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to move db files somewhere non-standard?  I use Mamp myself - seems to make all configuration.issues easier to deal with.

Comment: @Macmade The PHP module is active. I'm able to parse a phpinfo() test file.

Comment: @sparcksoft My online backup tool doesn't backup certain directories on my system partition. I wanted to move the db files so they can be included in the backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just using MAMP, but moving the mysql directory to a new location and doing a symlink to that location. Seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Nice.  Good solution.  MAMP FTW.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with magento-check.php is that the opening tag is `<?` rather than `<?php` - just fix that and you will be able to run magento-check.php just fine.